# Adding User access to DB2

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 10.1 in a Red hat box. During the installation I was asked to create several users (db2inst1, db2fenc1 etc). I have been using db2inst1 to perform all operations with DB2 and it works perfectly fine. The sqllib files are located in

`/home/db2inst1/sqllib`

The installation files are located in

`/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/`

All users have access to both these folders. I now want to perform the DB2 operations with another user, namely "john". Given that db2 uses the underlying user/password of the host machine, I added the groups dasadm1 and ds2iadm1 to the "john" user (which are the ones listed in db2inst1).

`uid=500(john) gid=500(john) groups=500(john),101(dasadm1),102(db2iadm1)`

I can properly enter the db2 cmd with the user "john"

`[john@rhel6 java]$ /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2`

but when I run my java app as user "john" I get the following error:

`SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][4.13.127] Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: db2jcct2 (Not found in java.library.path):  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null`

this error does not appear if I run the same java app as user db2inst1. The library paths are the exactly the same for both users. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Adding users to the default groups `db2iadm1` and `dasadm1` will provide elevated (`SYSADM`) privileges – you probably do not want to do that unless the user account is for a DBA.  Grant general user access either directly to the user IDs or using either operating system groups or database roles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gut feeling is that you did not update user "john's" profile to invoke the DB2 profile setup. If you do not do this, then you won't have "access" to DB2 per say, even though the binaries are there.

So what you want to do is write a script that checks for your DB2 instance "home" profile script
in your case it would be /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile and if it is there, to invoke it.

```
if [ -f /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile ] ; then
     . /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
     if [ ! $? = 0 ] ; then
          echo "Error setting up DB2 instance access"
     else
          echo "DB2 instance access set up"
     fi
fi
```

Comment: This solution will resolve both the command line and Java issues because it sets up both the DB2 command-line environment and the CLASSPATH.

Comment: How do I invoke the DB2 profile setup? Moreover, when I run your script it returns the latter: ""DB2 instance access set up"

Comment: @JohnPappas - Right. Now that you have DB2 instance access, you should be able to invoke it on the command line by just typing db2. (Meaning you wont' have to browse into instance directory to call DB2 functionality.).

Comment: [john@rhel ~]$ ./test.sh 
DB2 instance access set up
[john@rhel ~]$ db2
Command not found.

Comment: but  
[john@rhel ~]$ /home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2
(c) Copyright IBM Corporation 1993,2007
Command Line Processor for DB2 Client 10.1.0 ...... Yet this does not solve my problem in regards to the SQLException.

Comment: @JohnPappas - did you add your ID into the groups that Ian suggested above? You may need that. And generally you want this script run in your PROFILE so it is set up everytime you log in.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the db2 drivers on the classpath for the java app.