# Database name not found but I can connect using IBM Data Studio. What happened?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In IBM Data Studio, I can create a connection to a remote IBM DB2 LUW database named **DBEMP** and browse the schema and data.

Here is the steps to create the database connection:

1. From IBM Data Studio, In Database Adminstration Explorer, select: New -> New Connection to Database.
2. Select **DB2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows** in the dialog.
3. In General properties:

   Database: DBEMP
   Host: 10.221.5.111
   Port Number: 50001
   User Name: user1
   Password: *****
4. Click OK.

But when I tried to connect to the remote database server (AIX v7) via telnet command:

```
telnet 10.221.5.111
```

Note: I login using root user.

And then I run this command:

```
/db2/V10.1/bin/db2 connect to DBEMP
```

I got this error:

> SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "DBEMP" could not
>   be found. SQLSTATE=42705

Then I also run this command:

```
/db2/V10.1/bin/db2 list database directory
```

The result list doesn't have database named "DBEMP".

So what happened anyway?

If there is no database name exist, why IBM Data Studio can connect to it?

Comment: It appears you are referring to DB2 LUW. What are your connection details in Data Studio?

Comment: some of it might be how you telnet into the remote box. Agree with Warren. Please provide more details on how you set up the connection in Data Studio and now it exists on the remote server and how you are connecting to both.

Comment: @all: yes, it's LUW. I had added more details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh....That has to do with profiles. Root was not set up by default to have DB2 libraries set up in its profile, so it doesn't recognize the DB2 executables. This is not to say root can't do what you are asking, you would just have to browse to the /instance/bin folder to find the executables you are after. Of course, then you have to worry about whether or not root has permission to connect....

But anyway, you might find it easier to sudo over to the id you want to use to connect (possibly even the instance) `sudo - myid`. For sure the instance will have DB2 set up in its profile. Your other ID you may have to set it up. Here is an [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/adding-user-access-to-db2/31361#31361) I provided before where I showed someone how to set up DB2 for their profile.

I would recommend that you not give root DB2 access through its profile.

Comment: So did you mean I should login using **user1** (instead of root) in the telnet session and only then I could connect to the database?

Comment: I'm saying that root doesn't have DB2 set up in its profile. I don't know that user1 does either (it may or may not). You could try logging in as user1 and checking. If you don't have DB2 access you may need to navigate to your DB2 instance directory and invoke the db2profile script. Then you can use DB2. Make sense?

Comment: I tried login using **user1** and it works. So I guess you're right that the root user doesn't has db2 profile set up, but I wonder where is the db2profile script for root, I can't found it since root doesn't has home directory (the db2profile is in `/home/<user_name>/sqllib` directory)

Comment: I don't believe you would want root running DB2, but if you really wanted to you could just execute the db2profile script.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't really want to do that. I'm just curious how to do it if it's really possible. The problem is (like I stated before) I can't find db2profile script for root, because root doesn't has home directory. Another user (like **user1**) has db2profile script resides in their home directory. Note: the OS is IBM AIX v7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a beginner in db2 who try to help, I have the same problem too but I've resolved. It maybe caused when you're not store your database to catalog. Here's the command.

```
db2 catalog db DB_NAME at node YOUR_NODE
```