# configure client ibm_db2 for php

Tags: db2, php, redhat

I am installing a RHEL server with nginx and php that can connect to a db2 database, download and install the "IBM Data Server Client" package, also install the pecl library through:

> pecl install ibm_db2

however when I do a connectivity test me responds with the following error:

> [IBM] [CLI Driver] SQL10007N Message "0" could not be retrieved.
>   Reason code: "3". SQLCODE = -1390

the code that I'm testing is:

```
<?php
$database = 'mydb';
$user = 'usr';
$password = 'pass';
$hostname = 'ipaddr';
$port = 9501;

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" . "HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection succeeded.";
    db2_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo db2_conn_error();
    echo db2_conn_errormsg();
}
```

am I missing something?

Edit:

searching in the web I found in [phpe-ditors](http://www.php-editors.com/php_manual/ref.ibm-db2.html) this:

> If you created a DB2 instance named db2inst1 in /home/db2inst1/, for
>   example, you can add the following line to php.ini:
>
> ibm_db2.instance_name=db2inst1
>
> If you do not set this option in php.ini, you must issue the following
>   command to modify your environment variables to enable access to DB2:
>
> bash$ source /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
>
> To enable your PHP-enabled Web server to access these functions, you
>   must either set the ibm_db2.instance_name configuration option in
>   php.ini, or source the DB2 instance environment in your Web server
>   start script (typically /etc/init.d/httpd or /etc/init.d/apache).

The problem is that I don't know whats the value for ibm_db2.instance_name

Any idea ?

Comment: Looks like the DB2 environment is not set up properly. Make sure you execute `$INSTANCE_HOME/sqllib/db2profile` script.

Comment: If you are looking for how to set up the DB2 environment, this was answered in another question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31336/adding-user-access-to-db2

Comment: @mustaccio: I do not understand what it means in my case $INSTANCE_HOME. since I only installed the client, not the server. In the installation process I do not create specific users for the database, the installation script indicated that the client is in "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/". Found in that directory and ran a script called "db2profile" in the subdirectory "cfg" but the error persists. Note that the installation was done with the root user.

Comment: @Chirs Aldrich: the post that you refer is about install the database and I just want the client, that is because, is a web server that will host a php app that need database connection to an existing DB2 installation.

Comment: 1) it would be better to create a client instance using the command `db2icrt` ( [more details](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002057.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-5-2-6-62&lang=en) ) 2) make sure you _source_ the profile: `. /whatever/cfg/db2profile` -- note the space after the `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @mustaccio achieved do as follows:

First I added the user db2inst1:

> db2inst1 useradd

Then, I generated the instance (whatever it means)

> /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/instance/db2icrt db2inst1

Edit the php configuration file (/etc/php.ini) for add the instance:

```
 extension = / usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so 
 ibm_db2.instance_name = db2inst1
```

Edit the initialization file of the php-fpm service (/etc/init.d/php-fpm), which in my case is the one who runs php, to do the source of the db2profile script under the user running this service each time it starts.

```
 #for DB2
 . /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/cfg/db2profile
```

And finally restart the service:

> php-fpm restart service

Thank you very much for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction with the answer of @PCJ in my case

Added the user

```
useradd db2inst1
```

Ran the below command

```
/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/instance/db2icrt db2inst1
```

Edited php.ini and added below lines

```
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ibm_db2.so
ibm_db2.instance_name=db2inst1
```

Then restarted the apache service

To test the connectivity, used "Example #2 Creating an uncataloged connection" in [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php)